# Java Spring Boot Static Contents - Where Should I Put

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a problem with my js and css files in spring boot. I had another problem with pointing .html files yesterday but i solved it and now im trying to solve this problem. It seems similar with .html problem but i couldnt solve.

Here its my code.

## APPLICATION.JAVA (MAIN)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

## INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head lang="en">
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>           
        <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="topFrame">Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

## TYMELEAF CONFIG

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

## POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.berkin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kodgemisi.hr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.190</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## HOMECONTROLLER.JAVA

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(path="/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

## PICS

[image: 404 ERROR]

[image: FILE ORDER]

Am i have to write another config file for css and js files? Thanks

---

## SOLUTION

I have solved this problem now. You dont have to use config unless place your templates in src/main/resources folder. I moved everything into that folder than remove config file. Everything works perfectly now.

[image: SOLUTION]

Answer (score 0):

refer below image for directory location :-

[image]

[image]